# SVG filter width as percentage doesn't make sense — can it be specified as a margin?

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I am trying to create a **gaussian blur SVG filter** that can be reused without modification by people who are not programmers.

The problem I am running into is that the way the `width`, `height`, `x`, and `y`, values are defined doesn't seem appropriate for actual use.

```
<filter id="6pxBlur" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox"
  width="140%" x="-20%" height="140%" y="-20%">
  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="6"></feGaussianBlur>
</filter>
```

The `feGaussianBlur` filter is specified in pixels, so it would be useful to say "add a 6px margin to the original size to include the extra size added by blurring the shape."

Instead, the filter area is defined as a percentage of the original shape.

- it cuts off the edge of the filter effect with narrow shapes
- it includes a lot of extra space with wide shapes

[image: 6px gaussian blur on shapes with three different widths]

**Is there any way to define SVG filter width and height in terms of a margin relative to the original size?**

It looks like I'll end up using large width and height values just to be safe, but this will be inefficient and slow down page drawing in most cases.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Per the SVG specification calc is not allowed here although I think Chrome might allow it.

Comment: Wrap the SVG in a ``<svg-blur>`` Web Component that processes the SVG and (re)sets the correct filter

Comment: There is probably no need for a SVG filter definition. CSS `blur()` does the sizing of the filter region automatically and can be expressed [equivalently](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/#blurEquivalent) as a SVG `<feGaussianBlur>`. As long as a) `stdDeviation` is expressed as one value and b) `edgeMode` (only supported by Safari) is not used, the equivalence is bi-directional.

Comment: One option is to use filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" and specify x, y, width and height in viewBox units.